# Кнопка на экран

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Суть вопроса такова: Нужно вывести на экран телефона какую-нибудь кнопку, т.е чтобы при свернутом приложении или же просто в фоне всегда на экране была кнопка поверх всех приложений, чтобы при нажатии на которую, к примеру, показывался toast. Как это сделать?

Comment: так чтобы перекрыть экран - никак.

Comment: @SviatVolkov в google переводчик как то сделали же ..

Comment: Посмотрите демку https://github.com/noln/system-alert-window-example

Comment: @pavlofff в плане? речь же в вопросе идет о полном перекрытии всех ярлыков на хоум скрине.или я не правильно понял

Comment: @pavlofff, гугл переводчик использует какой-то ClipBoard API.. ТС-у нужно что-то наподобие очистки мусора системы как в Clean Master. Там такой кружок все перекрывает.

Comment: @flippy какая разница, кто инициатор события, главное в данном случае, что вывести кнопку поверх всего вполне возможно